# Changing the color of cell upon duplicate, triplicate entry in a row

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I currently have a Conditional Formatting set up to color code the cell Green if DBSK is entered for the first time within a row.  Although, if a second entry of DBSK is entered within the same row, I need that cell to turn Yellow (to alarm the user that this is the second incident) and then if the same entry is made a 3rd time within the row, I need that cell to then turn red (to alarm the user that this is the third and last incident allowed).  Maybe I should eliminate the Conditional Formatting altogether and just have some code written against it?

Comment: You mean when the string "DBSK" is entered? Or what do you mean by DBSK?

Answer (score 1):

I do it as an example in the range C2:H10

First select the range like this:

[image]

Then click on `Conditional formatting` and select `new rule`.

Select the last rule type: with formular.

You should edit the rule like this: **Sorry, my excel has Hungarian settings :)**

[image]

Take a look at the formular:

```
=ÉS(C2="DBSK"; DARABTELI($C2:$H2;"DBSK")=2)
```

In English it is something like this, but you can corrert if not good the syntax:

```
=AND(C2="DBSK", COUNTIF($C2:$H2,"DBSK")=2)
```

`C2`: The top-left cell of the range. **Important:** without $

`$C2:$H2`: The first row. **Important:** $ only before the C and H not before the numbers.

After that create the next rule: click on `Conditional formatting` and select `new rule` again.

This rule looks like this.

[image]

The end result looks like this:

[image]

After that you can create the first rule for the green formatting similarly with the rule `=AND(C2="DBSK", COUNTIF($C2:$H2,"DBSK")=1)`